# after cv.normalize(), the pixels of result is 0 , why?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to normalize the picture's data, using OpenCV's funciton `cv.normalize()`, but after `cv.normalize()`, the result is always 0, which should be a float value from 0 to 1.

I have tried all the parameters to `cv.normalize()`, but that didn't help.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2

im = Image.open("./dataset/0001.jpg")

new_img2 = im.resize((64, 64), Image.BILINEAR)

mat = np.asarray(new_img2.convert('RGB'))  
mat = mat.reshape(1, 64, 64, 3)
print(mat)  

cv2.normalize(mat, mat, 1, 0,  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
print(mat)


[[[[ 46  46  46]
   [ 50  50  50]
   [ 52  52  52]
   ...
   [ 14  14  14]
   [ 13  13  13]
   [ 13  13  13]]
   ...

    -------------------------------

[[[[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]
   ...
   [0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]
   ...
```

Comment: if set alpha=1, beta=0, it's alway wrong , but if i set alpha=0, beta=255,  it can give right  result, but i want to get float value ,not int  value , where is wrong , i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy, not need to use normalize:

```
res = np.float32(mat)

res /= 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the output data type is set to float

```
mat = cv2.normalize(mat, mat, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_32F)
```